# onkeyup="check()" on <p:password> shows null for input element values

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

In primefaces 3.0.M3, While using document.getElementById('confirmPassword') for getting textBox value to javaScript, which gives a null value!
Code is:
in primefaces:

```
<h:outputText value="Confirm Password*" />
<p:password
value="#{employeeRepositoryImpl.securityPrincipals.confirmPassword}"
required="true" label="Confirm Password" id="confirmPassword" for="confirmPassword" onkeyup="check()" >
update="confirmPassword" />
</p:password>
```

in javaScript:

```
function check(){
    var title1 = document.getElementById('confirmPassword'); 
    var title2 = document.getElementById('password'); 
    alert(title1+title2);}
```

I have set prependId="false" . But alert shows null.Any other way to do the same?

Comment: When are you calling this function ? and Did you check with generated HTML is it the same id ?

Comment: Calling on onkeyup="check()".

Comment: and can you post HTML snippet generated for this XHTML

Comment: You mean this one? <input id="formId:confirmPassword_input" class="ui-inputfield ui-password ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="password" onkeyup="checkPass()" value="fd" name="formId:confirmPassword_input">

Comment: Why don't you just use `<p:password confirm>` for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, the HTML that is generated is as below

```
<input id="formId:confirmPassword_input" class="ui-inputfield ui-password ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" type="password" onkeyup="checkPass()" value="fd" name="formId:confirmPassword_input">
```

which means still form appends id from it, please recheck your `h:form` under which these components lies and set the `prependId="false"`

and if you try to get the HTML dom with id `confirmPassword` it will return `null` where the actual ID in HTML is `formId:confirmPassword_input`

Comment: I have already set prependId="false".When I changed the  function with 'password_input' it is ok...like, checkPass(){            
  var title1 = document.getElementById('password_input').value; 
  var title2 =ocument.getElementById('confirmPassword_input').value; 
  alert(title1+title2); }